# Non-Capturing Group: Remove 3rd value

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to construct an Regular Expression for additional parameters.

My URL can have following values:

- **Works:** domain.tld/app/`{$ID}`-`{$URL_FRIENDLY_NAME}`
- **Works:** domain.tld/app/`{$ID}`-`{$URL_FRIENDLY_NAME}`/`{$ACTION}`
- **Problem:** domain.tld/app/`{$ID}`-`{$URL_FRIENDLY_NAME}`/`{$ACTION}`/`{$TAB}`

Here is my Regular Expression:

> '^/app/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+|new)(?:/(delete|config(?:/(info|ftp|logs))?))?$

`{$ACTION}` and `{$TAB}` is an optional parameter.

For sample, **this Scheme works**:

- domain.tld/app/1-testname

  - It's open the Main-View of the App
- domain.tld/app/1-testname/delete

  - When you want to delete the App
- domain.tld/app/1-testname/config

  - Configurations-Page of the App

Additional i want to create Subpages on my `config`-Page:

- domain.tld/app/1-testname/config/info

  - Config-Informations
- domain.tld/app/1-testname/config/logs

  - Logfiles of the App
- domain.tld/app/1-testname/config/ftp

  - FTP Configuration

My Problem is the last Non-Capturing Group `(?:/(info|ftp|logs))?`- The results of the Matches correct, but not from the previous Non-Capturing Group.

Without the last Group, the Result is following, thats **correct**:

```
Full match `/app/1-testname/config`
Group 1.    `1`
Group 2.    `testname`
Group 3.    `config

Full match `/app/1-testname/delete`
Group 1.    `1`
Group 2.    `testname`
Group 3.    `delete`
```

Here is the Result of the last Non-Capturing Group:

```
Full match `/app/1-testname/config/logs`
Group 1.    `1`
Group 2.    `testname`
Group 3.    `config/logs`
Group 4.    `logs`
```

And here, you see my Problem: `Group 3` has the Value of `Group 4`.

My concrete question is: **How i can remove `/logs`on `Group 3`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to rearrange your grouping a bit, like `^/app/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+|new)(?:/(?:(delete|config)(?:/(info|ftp|logs))?))?$`. This makes your group 3 a non capturing one and explicitly captures only `delete|config`.

Site note: In `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+|new` the alternative is pointless, as `new` is already matched by the repeated character class.

Comment: Thanks, the rearrange work's :) And yes, the `new`-Keyword is here misplaced; The `new` must to the `{$ID}` - Had added the URL-Friendly name yesterday but forget to move the `new` to my ID.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this regexp:

```
^\/app\/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+|new)(?:\/(delete|config)(?:\/(info|ftp|logs))?)?$
```